# Regex to Parse from Clipboard

Tags: regex

I'm trying to read each line of data in the clipboard and parse the needed data. The clipboard data is as follows:

```
ABC Heating and AC
John Smith
johm@abcHVAC.com
```

I'm trying to read the first line to set `company` to the full company name. From the second line, set `fname` to the first name, and `lname` to the last name. From the third line, I would like to extract the email address as `email`.

Here is what I have so far.

```
RegExMatch(clipboard,"\V+",company)
RegExMatch(clipboard,"\n.*?(?:\s(?=\w+\S))", fname)
RegExMatch(clipboard,"`n`n\V+",lname)
RegExMatch(clipboard,"\n\n.*?(?:\s(?=\w+\S))",email)
```

I've tried a variety of expressions and just can't seem to get there. I have the company and the first name parsing, but can't seem to get the other two fields.

Comment: Is this .NET code and are you running on Windows?

Comment: I think it would be easier and cleaner to split this clipboard string by line break and then check each individual piece.

Comment: This is autohotkey.

Comment: Try this for the email: `RegExMatch(clipboard, ".*\n(\V+)", email)`

Comment: Yea - that didn't work for just the email address. That actually provides everything from the first name to the email address